# How to use and understand: Kettle of fish

Tags: phrase-meaning, idioms

On Mathematica.SE I found:

> What distribution this tuple follows is a different **kettle of fish**.

I would like to understand how and when to use the phrase *kettle of fish* and why it can be used alongside with *pretty* or *whole-new*.

Comment: Have you tried to do a Google search for "[kettle of fish define](https://www.google.com/#q=kettle+of+fish+define)"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*A whole nother kettle of fish* (or similar) is an idiomatic way of saying **it's a different concept altogether**.

> **kettle of fish** *noun*
>
> a state of affairs

*Source: Dictionary.com*